# AWS::S3::Errors::ExpiredToken with Paperclip when uploading for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api, amazon-s3, paperclip

I currently have a Rails API with AngularJS frontend that upload picture to Amazon S3.  But when I do, I get that error: `AWS::S3::Errors::ExpiredToken The provided token has expired.`.

The strange thing is that if I reupload a file right away, it works.  I guess when the token expired, it try to get a new one and the upload works on the second time.

My code is pretty basic, no need to share.  I included basic paperclip functionality into my model and my configuration file are fine too.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you using an instance profile to get credentials to the instance?

Comment: Not sure about your question, but I use environment variable in my config to get those credentials and they are set in my elastic beanstalk configuration.  The user that manage the elastic beanstalk have full access to the S3.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems are due to IAM permissions.

Make sure your permissions are on the same users as your elastic bean stalk.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your local or server has the correct time setup.

If you server is few minutes ahead of the AWS server it will fail the first time but will work few minutes after.

Comment: Everything is setup on Amazon, I don't think they would have setup the elastic beanstalk with the wrong time. For the s3, I have no control over there.  Thanks, This could had been the issue.

Comment: how would you `Make sure your local or server has the correct time setup.`